# How do I return column data from database which implements DBO?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch the 'id' column data from my database. Since the purpose of this is a login, there is only one potential row that is returned for the SQL query I have used. I would like to create a reference (`$this->result`) for the id of the user so that I can use this later on. At the moment it appears nothing is being retrieved from `$this->result = $stmt->fetchColumn()`; Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can make this work?

```
$sql='SELECT id FROM member WHERE username=:var and password=:var2';

            try {
                $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(":var", $myusername);
                $stmt->bindParam(":var2", $mypassword);
                $stmt->execute();
            } catch(PDOException $ex) {
                echo "An Error occured!";
                some_logging_function($ex->getMessage());
            }
            $this->count = $stmt->rowCount();

            $this->result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Are you sure your query is returning a result?

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->result)` return?  We don't see the PDO constructor here, but did you actually set PDO to throw exceptions with `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`? By default it errors silently.

Comment: @crush there is definitely no problem with the query and it's execution

Comment: @Dan How can you be sure? What steps have you taken? You haven't told us anything about what is the result of `$this->count` or `$this->result`. You've only told us that "nothing is retrieved" which seems indicative of either your query not returning a result, or it not executing properly.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes it is set to throw the exception that you mentioned.